# I need to convert text file to excel sheet

Tags: excel, python-3.x, text

I am trying to upload data to mysql. that text file is in table format,i need to convert into excel sheet,text is as follows:

```
AC NO PART NO SR NO Voter Name ID CARD NO GENDER AGE    
195 5 747 अमर सुदाम नाडेकर AFB8066037 M 22
195 12 502 अमर बाळु सुकाळे AFB1833029 M 29
195 20 1014 अमर सुदाम नाडेकर AFB8272858 M 22
195 22 449 अमर रामचंद्र भालिंगे AFB8121022 M 22
195 29 379 अमरदीप एकनाथ कुमकर AFB8068603 M 20
195 36 617 अमर तानाजी डुंबरे AFB7546203 M 30
195 37 360 अमर सिताराम तांबे AFB7987993 M 23
```

i tried some code it gives me CSV format like this :

```
"AC,NO,PART,NO,SR,NO,Voter,Name,ID,CARD,NO,GENDER,AGE,,,,
","195,5,747,अमर,सुदाम,नाडेकर,AFB8066037,M,22
","195,12,502,अमर,बाळु,सुकाळे,AFB1833029,M,29
","195,20,1014,अमर,सुदाम,नाडेकर,AFB8272858,M,22
","195,22,449,अमर,रामचंद्र,भालिंगे,AFB8121022,M,22
","195,29,379,अमरदीप,एकनाथ,कुमकर,AFB8068603,M,20
","195,36,617,अमर,तानाजी,डुंबरे,AFB7546203,M,30
","195,37,360,अमर,सिताराम,तांबे,AFB7987993,M,23
","195,42,450,अमर,आशोक,हांडे,FTV1708460,M,35
```

this is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

f = open('voters_search_results1.txt')

x = f.readlines()
s = []

for i in x:
  i = i.replace(","," ")
  j = i.replace(" ",",")
  s.append(j)

csvex = csv.writer(open("txt2csv_export.csv","w"), delimiter= ','  
     ,quoting= csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
csvex.writerow(s)


df = pd.read_csv('txt2csv_export.csv')
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

when i try to upload it to mysql is thows this error:

> """raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
>   xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected
>   BOF record; found b'"AC,NO,P' """

Answer (score 0):

Your output file field delimiter looks wrong and has a double quote at the start of the row but no matching end double quote, CSVs should be something like :

```
"AC","NO","PART","NO","SR"... etc
```

Try adding quotechar to split the fields with a " in the format:

```
csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Comment: can you expand on that? what does your output csv look like now?

Comment: "AC,NO,PART,NO,SR,NO,Voter,Name,ID,CARD,NO,GENDER,AGE,,,,
","195,5,747,अमर,सुदाम,नाडेकर,AFB8066037,M,22
","195,12,502,अमर,बाळु,सुकाळे,AFB1833029,M,29
","195,20,1014,अमर,सुदाम,नाडेकर,AFB8272858,M,22
","195,22,449,अमर,रामचंद्र,भालिंगे,AFB8121022,M,22
","195,29,379,अमरदीप,एकनाथ,कुमकर,AFB8068603,M,20
","195,36,617,अमर,तानाजी,डुंबरे,AFB7546203,M,30
","195,37,360,अमर,सिताराम,तांबे,AFB7987993,M,23
","195,42,450,अमर,आशोक,हांडे,FTV1708460,M,35

Comment: everytime i try to open it in LibreOffice,it asks for delimiter. I think that is the reason data is not parsing into mysql. How can i set it to default delimiter so it open like normal excel files?

Comment: trying replacing, the line j = i.replace(" ",",") with j = i.replace(' ','","')